# Copy javascript object with private member

Tags: javascript, object, clone, private

I've looked all around and found nothing to help me. Why on earth can't I clone a javascript object with private members without making them quantum entangled?

Just look at this code... It's a plain private property with getter and setter.
Somehow if I call the public setter on one instance, the cloned one gets changed too. Why? Can it be worked around?

```
obj = function(){
    var changed = 0;
    this.getChanged = function(){
        return changed;
    }
    this.setChanged = function(){
        changed = 1;
    }
    this.setUnchanged = function(){
        changed = 0;
    }
};

myObj = new obj();
copiedObj = $.extend(true, {}, myObj); // Or any other deep copy function you'd have around

myObj.setChanged();
myObj.getChanged(); // returns 1
copiedObj.getChanged(); // returns 1!
copiedObj.setUnchanged();
copiedObj.getChanged(); // returns 0
myObj.getChanged(); // returns 0
```

Thanks for any ideas.

**Edit**: So far, nothing new. I know javascript doesn't really have OO like Java or C++, but hey we're talking about programming languages, there is always one way out. Sometimes it's ugly but there is one.

I get it. 
Solution A: just make it **this.changed** instead of **var changed**
Solution B: make my own clone function that rebuilds the whole object anew

I was just hoping there would be some Solution C that would trick javascript into standard Object Oriented patterns.

Somebody, am I really stuck with A or B?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that **changed** isn't a private variable-- JavaScript doesn't have private variables. It's a local variable to the function you assign to the **obj** variable. When you create the functions that get assigned to the **getChanged** / **setChanged** / **setUnchanged** properties, you're creating [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) that are closed over the variable **changed**.

When you clone **myObj**, you're just creating additional aliases to those functions. So, you're still calling the same functions regardless of whether you access them through **myObj** or **copiedObj**, and because they're closures, you're accessing exactly the same **changed** variable in both cases. Since you can't copy functions, you're better off not trying to make **changed** private and just doing **this.changed = 0;** on the second line.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables in functions that are used as *constructors* are called "private members" so Java masses can understand the intention of the usage. It doesn't work like a property. It is a local variable in a lexical scope. It is "private" to the instance, not the class. There are no classes in javascript.

Your best bet is adding a clone method that will deep copy the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Even a deep copy can't copy a function as anything but a reference.  And since your functions are closures, they all share the same private members.  Why not write a `clone()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer.

gilly3's hint helped.

The clone/deep-copy function I was using in fact was not jQuery's but the one [A. Levy posted on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript/728694#728694).

Had to tweak it in two ways to work as I expected. In fact the original author had pointed out the way in his explanation but I didn't catch it at the time I first read it.
First I instantiated the copy with the original object's constructor and
Filtered out functions from the for in loop.

Here's the result. Hope that helps someone.

```
function clone(obj) {
    // Handle the 3 simple types, and null or undefined
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;

    // Handle Date
    if (obj instanceof Date) {
        var copy = new Date();
        copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Array
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        var copy = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; ++i) {
            copy[i] = clone(obj[i]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Object (functions are skipped)
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        var copy = new obj.constructor();
        for (var attr in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr) && !(obj[attr] instanceof Function)) copy[attr] = clone(obj[attr]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    throw new Error("Unable to copy obj! Its type isn't supported.");
}
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that you're not actually cloning the value of the **changed** variable using this method. If that's a requirement, you'll need a clone method specific to your obj "class" that uses **getChanged** / **setChanged** to transfer the value.

Comment: Yes. In my case the changed variable is specific to the instance and has a default in the constructor. I don't want that to be copied, so that's ok. Thanks.